# Export html table into pdf using blob

Tags: angularjs, pdf, blob

i want to know that how can i export pdf file from angularjs. I've exported excel file and it is working fine.

following is code for excel

view.html

```
<button ng-click="vm.exportData()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>&nbsp; Download as pdf</button>
```

controller.js

```
 $scope.exportData = function () {
        debugger;
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('export').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        window.saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
    },
```

how to do 
`type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"` <======this linein pdf?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have u tried
`'type': 'application/pdf'`

Comment: Just as @CodingNinja said, 'type': 'application/pdf' should be work

Comment: Yes... i tried that, the file gets downloaded but gives the error "Failed to load pdf content" when i try to open it..

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You can retrieve the pdf content as ArrayBuffer by set responseType:

```
  $http({
                url: url,
                method: method,
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': _type
                },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer' //set response type
            })
```

Note:

type -> 'application/pdf'

fileContent -> should be an ArrayBuffer

```
downloadFile(filename, 'application/pdf', fileContent);

function downloadFile(filename, type, fileContent) {
    var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {type: type});
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute('href', url);
            link.setAttribute('download', filename);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, m not sure where should i use the response type as "array buffer" because i have defined that function on a button click inside its controller and not calling it through any http link..

Comment: If you content isn't binary data from server, you can check this lib out:https://code.google.com/archive/p/jspdf